# Bitmaps and OutOfMemoryError despite performing recycle

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm facing a problem that I can't seem to get to the root of.

In my View, I have a LinearLayout of dynamically added Customer Views of which the background is an ImageView (implemented with RemoteImageView from ignition library that downloads image from URLs and display them in an ImageView). I've tried to optimize these images for both tablets and mobile phones, so I scaled to maximum width to 800px while preserving aspect ratio.

For an example of how the activity looks like: http://imgur.com/O6eur

It is basically a ScrollLayout > LinearLayout > with up to a large amount of dynamically added custom views with a background of ImageView.

The images are at of a maximum of 800px width, so height might be more if its a portrait image. .These are by no means small images.

These images load fine on first start of the activity. However should I exit this activity, and enter another activity with just any one of these image, I will face an OutOfMemoryError with BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()

This is weird, because I actually do call recycle on bitmaps, and it is in fact show in Logcat that I do.

On startup of the app: heres the GC alloc:

> 01-19 13:20:59.430: D/dalvikvm(30793): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2%
>   free 17969K/18311K, paused 1ms+2ms

So you can see it has about 17969k free.

On enter activity, the heap grows:

01-19 13:22:26.090: D/dalvikvm(30793): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 45812K/46983K, paused 2ms+19ms

Now it uses 45812K.

When I exit (I do a finish() onPause), I recycle the bitmaps from all the imageviews, and the memory turns to this:

01-19 13:23:30.150: D/dalvikvm(30793): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26999K, 60% free 19170K/46983K, paused 8ms+20ms

We are down to 19170K.

Should I enter the activity again, it will crash with OutOfMemoryError. Now the thing is, I'm using the latest phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) to test this, and I would like my app to work on older phones with lesser memory, and I'm sure it would not support as much memory that I have right now.

I am wondering what can I do to display as many images I have as possible without fear of an OutOfMemoryError? I had earlier assumed that using RemoteImageView would cache the Bitmaps (https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition), but I am however wrong and I'm still facing the problem. What can I do to prevent this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write virtual scrolling. You should have in memory only displayed images and handle scroll events for repositionig widgets and load new images into memory.